# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT

Tags: laravel, forms, methods, routes

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367qG.png)

[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nS8K.png)

[productsController

Comment: make the method as POST and try...

Comment: Instaed of screenshot,put the code here..

Comment: It would be great if you can put the code here, so that we can between evaluate the problem you are facing.

Comment: Please clean up your question so it is clearer

Answer (score 1):

Change your `web.php` file

```
  Route::post('/update/{id}','productsController@update')->name('product.update');
```

In your view

```
 <form action="{{route('product.update',['id' => $products->id])}}" method="post">
```

Replace `@method('PUT')` with

```
   <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Comment: The route should be `Route::put(...)` as you are passing `PUT` in the `_method` field.

Comment: POST will work fine..Actually no need of the hidden PUT field.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `method="PUT"` and place `method="POST"` from `<form ...>` tag. Also, I'm not sure about this @method('PUT'). I will use something like this: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>`